# Proper markup for modifying CSS after javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the proper markup for modifying the CSS *after* a javascript function builds a div? I am familiar with using jquery's `.css()`  however, I am not sure how to create an event handler for when the js is done loading its resources. The javascript comes from a third party and looks like this - it also creates horrible inline styles:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsfunction(){
    var x = (content);
    var y = document.createElement("script");
    js.setAttribute("language", "javascript");
    js.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    js.setAttribute("src",x + "scriptUrl");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(js);
}
if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent("onload", jsfunction);}
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener("load", jsfunction, false);}
else {document.addEventListener("load", jsfunction, false);}
</script>
```

Comment: That code isn't modifying the CSS, it's attaching a whole new stylesheet to the document. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That code not only adds a new stylesheet, but it gives you pure-JS event listeners that you can use to alter elements post-load. If they can modify the jsfunction to add a callback, you could put your code in there.

Comment: d_either, could you give an example? That is what I was asking how to do. I just don't know how to attach my code. I was going to use the this: `$("#divname").css({'width': '100%', 'position': 'relative'});`

Comment: Sure, it's untested, but I've included it below.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it will override the existing jsfunction (assuming you can't get the third-party to change it), apply it, and then existing your css changing code after. Since jsfunction is already bound to document load, it should execute.

Keep in mind, this is not tested and I'm not sure whether the document load will use this override over the original, but it's worth a shot.

```
// Keep a reference to the older function.
var old_jsfunction = jsfunction;

// Redefine jsfunction
jsfunction = function() {
  old_jsfunction.apply(old_jsfunction, arguments);

  $("#divname").css({'width': '100%', 'position': 'relative'});
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work for me. :-( Perhaps this is because the div is being generated from the script this function is pulling in?

Comment: Is there any way you can get the third-party to modify the jsfunction as delivered?